# Replace driver side first, then passenger side brakes?

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor

Need advice.  I am replacing brake rotors and pads for all four wheels.  My home 2-car garage only gives me enough room to work on the side facing the other car, the middle of the garage. Is it safe to install the rotors and pads on both the front and rear passenger wheels first - then back the car out of the garage and pull it back in on the other side so that the driver side gets the room to work?  Any problem doing one side and then the other instead of both front and then both rear?

Comment: What is the make ,model, and year of the car?

Comment: Honda Accord EX 2004

Comment: Can you back the other car out to give to you more room? I think most people replace the front brakes or rear brakes. I can't find anything on replacing left or right side brakes at separate times.

Comment: Agreed that both front together and both rear together is normal, but my garage doesn't give me that space.  My driveway has steep slope up to garage so I don't want to stick half the car out to then try to work on a slope.

Comment: park the ok car on the street, move the car needing new brakes to the middle of the garage (park diagonally if needed to get round a central pillar at the doors, park ok car on the drive... you should have enough room them.  Additionally just to clarify you don't mean to run the car with only one side new brakes you only mean to do one side, turn the car around and then do the others?

Comment: Correct.  Just mean to replace one side, then immediately switch car to other side of garage and then replace the other side.  I'm not able to park it diagonally even with other car gone.

Comment: Please see the bold section below in my answer. Can you use go jaks to change the position of the car in the garage? If you move the other car you might be able to change the position of the car you are servicing with go jaks. - Depending on the size of your vehicle it may work.

Comment: This is perfectly fine, and you are right to avoid things like changing them on your sloping driveway.  It if doesn't feel safe don't do it.  For longer term driving only changing one side can cause you to spin out when you apply the brakes a speed because one side grabs better. But if you are not driving faster than you walk then no worries.

Comment: It's totally okay to do one side then back out and do the other- there's no issue.

Comment: personally, in this situation I'd still get one end done at a time, which would require turning the car around twice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have a very good reason for not taking the other car out of the garage to give yourself more room...

People replace either the front or rear brakes together because they are "on the same axle" and replacing one side doesn't make sense because both sides should wear at the same rate.  Replacing one side could make the car pull to one side or other strange behavior.

That said, I don't see any reason you can't change one side immediately before changing the other side.  I wouldn't drive very much like that because how the brakes might react is hard to predict, but if you're literally just backing out and then back in - go for it.

Before backing up, make sure that the brakes have pressure. I'd hate for you to introduce air into the lines then try to back up and keep going because the brakes don't work!

Comment: you'll also have the advantage of being able to look at the other side, still assembled, for reference when reassembling the brakes. in fact, haynes manuals usually recommend doing each brake completely before moving on to the next brake for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

I found two videos that may help to move the car into a better position to work with.

This should help with your workspace problem.

One video uses Gojaks and the other system uses something similar to furniture coasters.

Gojaks are useful for moving cars in and out tight spaces.

Park and Slide (Car coasters)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xj7TYSBAGpU

Gojaks

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKg6fMIIoX0

If your garage is large enough perhaps in the future you can use a system like the one in this video below. It's a car lift that places cars up towards a ceiling. Some are single lifts I think this one has two separate lifts.

Car storage lift

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vHdGshWSE0

Comment: This doesn't answer the question the OP asked, and it doesn't seem right to just copy an entire webpage as an answer.  I feel like this should be removed.

Comment: @JPhi1618 There are two questions one was "Any problem doing one side and then the other instead of both front and then both rear?" If you disagree with my answer to this question I shall remove it. I have posted a few answers to questions so far and I have been told to post the website content in case the website is down or removed.

Comment: You can edit your answer, but I think the direct copy is a problem.  You can link to an external article and quote a few important, minimal parts, but then you should explain in your words why that is important and how it helps the OP with his question.

Comment: And for the "post website content" comments... They mean to post the relevant excerpts from the site - not the whole page.  And like I said, you should still provide your own supporting introduction and explanation for the source material.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Should I post the website content if asked for it in other questions? I have been asked at least three or more times to post an entire article and not just leave the url. - Due to a website being down etc. Yes, I have explained in my own words before and the importance of the article.

Comment: Is their any difference for a video clip or picture with that type of content?

Comment: I see from that answer that it states: "Do one side, then the other: For reasons that will be clear later, you should change the pads on one side of the car from start to finish before doing the other side." but then never explains why - and actually in contradiction to this claim instructs to do the other side of the front brakes next instead of the rear brakes on the same side.  Confused.

Comment: @okorng Is your question geared more towards work space or the order in which you should do the brakes?

Comment: @okorng, exactly.  It doesn't answer your question.  mr_tuner, I'm really not trying to discourage you - just trying to help you post proper answers. A video link with no explanation that provides an exhaustive how-to rather than being directly related to the question would be just as bad.

Comment: Workspace.  I know that the same axle should have its brakes changed together, but I don't have room in my garage to make that happen - so one side at a time seems like my only option.

Comment: I obviously misread the article's statement "Do one side, then the other: For reasons that will be clear later, you should change the pads on one side of the car from start to finish before doing the other side." to mean replace both front and rear on same side before doing the other side.  Did it mean to convey replacing both inner and outer pads on one side (of front) before doing same on other side of front?

Comment: Are you bleeding the brake system at the same time you are changing the driver side or passenger side? <Here is what my previous answer had in the article I posted> Do one side, then the other: For reasons that will be clear later, you should change the pads on one side of the car from start to finish before doing the other side. Also, since you're doing one side at a time, turn the steering wheel so that the wheel you're working on is angled out for better access to the brakes.

Comment: I hadn't planned to. Is that necessary?

Comment: It's recommended to bleed the brake system when brakes are changed. Your owners manual may have an answer when to change the brake fluid. All credit to my earlier comment and post goes to How To Change Your Brake Pads
Save Money With This Easier-Than-Expected DIY Project

Updated: 09/20/2011  - by Philip Reed, Senior Consumer Advice Editor Dan Edmunds, Director of Vehicle Testing

Comment: I still don't see the "reasons that will be clear later, you should change the pads on one side of the car from start to finish before doing the other side.".  What are the reasons?

Comment: Some reasons may be for easiness. Once you change the brakes on one side the passenger side or the drivers side it may disturb the vehicles braking performance. I think that is what they are getting at. I have never seen somebody work on sides of a car only the front and the back. - I think that is why it is very difficult to find something about the order of the brake change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37127/discussion-between-mr-tuner-and-okorng).

Answer (score 1):

If you are just going to move the car to get into a better position to work on then this is fine.

One important thing to be aware of though is that if you have done anything which might allow air into the braking system eg disconnecting pistons or any other part of the brake hydraulics then the hydraulic brakes may not work at all well until you bleed them. So take great care and don't perform any maneuvers which require sharp braking and test that the handbrake/emergency brake works well beforehand and be ready to use it.